# Parse JSON without relying on order

Tags: php, json

I have this JSON, I'm parsing. I can retrieve all the values of field_data in order in PHP, but I need to traverse and get the values I wan't by specifying the field name, without concern for order:

JSON

```
{
   created_time: "2018-05-14T16:11:02+0000",
   id: "555555555555",
   field_data: [
   {
        name: "bedrooms_interested_in?",
        values: [
        "2"
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "When_are_you_looking?",
        values: [
        "January 1s 2019"
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "email",
        values: [
        "xxxx@domain.com"
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "full_name",
        values: [
        "John Michael"
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "phone_number",
        values: [
        "+15555555555"
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

PHP

This is grabbing the last 3 fields. I'm currently able to pull the `fields_data` in order like this, but how could I grab the value fields I want by specifying the name field I'm looking for?

```
   $data = json_decode($response, true);
    // var_dump($data);
        file_put_contents('dump.txt', $response);
    $lead_email = $data['field_data'][2]['values'][0];
    $lead_fullname = $data['field_data'][3]['values'][0];
    $lead_phone = $data['field_data'][4]['values'][0];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to re-index an array by a given column, which will give you easier and more reliable access to the data:

```
$data['field_data'] = array_column($data['field_data'], null, 'name');
```

This allows you to access fields by name instead of their numeric index, e.g.

```
echo $data['field_data']['email']['values'][0];
// xxxx@domain.com
```

See https://eval.in/1003874 for a full example

(Note, I added some quotes to your JSON property names, since they were missing in the question. I assume that's a formatting issue, since this wouldn't work at all otherwise)

Comment: @Omar Not directly, but there is an `array_column` polyfill for versions earlier than 5.5 here: https://github.com/ramsey/array_column

Comment: Yes!! I wasnt able to test without this include because I have 5.4. Thank you so much! This did it.